# Django template engine indentation

Tags: django, django-templates, indentation

I'm having a hard time trying to get Django's template engine to indent properly when extending/including templates

these files :

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="hello">
            {% block bar %}
            {% endblock %}

            {% include 'baz.html'%}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`bar.html`

```
{% extends 'foo.html' %}

{% block bar %}
<p>bar</p>
{% endblock %}
```

`baz.html`

```
<p>baz</p>
```

will render as

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="hello">
<p>bar</p>
<p>baz</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it so it renders as

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="hello">
            <p>bar</p>
            <p>baz</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Manually entering tabs is not an option.
I am using soft tabs (4 spaces) if ever this matters.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would matter. Browsers ignore indentation anyway, the only reason for it is to make it easier to read in your text editor - and there you'd never see the full rendered page anyway.

Comment: I could be useful when debugging since you won't know how it rendered after all from django.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indentation is not automatically inserted by Django template inheritence. To achieve the indentation you desire you'd need to include it within `bar.html`:

```
{% extends 'foo.html' %}

{% block bar %}
            <p>bar</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is there really no other way ?  
I will end up with files having 6 levels of indentation..

Comment: Really. You would have to write your own `{% block %}` tag.

Answer (score 4):

You should explain with is the purpose of your indentation needs.

Indentation is very useful in debug step, but indentation is not compatible with optimization, because this exists [spaceless](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless) filter.

You can write your own snipped:

```
@register.tag
def myinden(parser, token):
    args = token.contents.split()
    n = args[1]
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endmyinden',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return MyIndenNode(nodelist, n)

class MyIndenNode(Node, n):
    def __init__(self, nodelist, n):
        self.nodelist = nodelist
        self.n = n

    def render(self, context):
        import re
        regex = re.compile("^", re.M)
        return re.sub(regex, "\t"*int(self.n),
                      self.nodelist.render(context).strip())
```

To usage:

```
index.html
{% include 'baz.html' with indentation="8" %}

baz.html
{{ myindent:myindentation }}
...
```

Notice, not tested. Also, I suggest to you to modify snippet to works only in debug mode:

Comment: It's only for myself, really. I don't like having files like this https://gist.github.com/3c73384133e553ad6567  
If I had to face a file like this I would be wondering why there are so much spaces at first.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the NodeList's render method as I've done. See my question with working code:

[Proper indentation in Django templates (without monkey-patching)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308626/how-to-modify-django-template-system-without-monkey-patching-to-achieve-proper)

Answer (score 1):

Another option from the above mentioned is to use Beautiful Soup middleware.

Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.christianperone.com/?p=814). Note, that people call this middleware to be ``[REALLY SLOW](http://blog.christianperone.com/?p=814#comment-3429)'' and advice caching the output pages.